# Change facebook post details using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to change the details of a facebook post using php ?

I have created the post from my own application and for example I want to change image.

can we do such thing ? php or javascript ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't think is possbile to change the image after you submit as Facebook caches every image and stores them on their own servers.

Comment: That was an example. but can I change anything else ? say the "name"

Comment: as @zerkms said I don't think eighter you can change anything. You can delete the post and repost.

Comment: ok, thanks. is it possible to add comments and likes from the old post that I'm deleting to the new post ?

Comment: Nope, if the comments and likes done by another users - it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Facebook doesn't support editing of posts from either user interface or API

I bet it has been made for performance purposes